# C++ const static initiation based on input

Tags: c++, static, constants

Hello guys i have static problem with my class:

```
class Monster
{
private:
     static const bool hard; 
     //more staff here
};
```

I know that i can initiate it like const bool Monster::hard

But I want to know if i can initiate based on users input
Something like If(wantToBeHard) hard = true;
This means it must be in a method or something right?
There is any way to do this?

Comment: This member looks like it should be neither `const` nor `static`.

Comment: @Jon if non-`static`, it may be `const` and initialized by constructor based on input. If non-`const`, it may be `static` and changed by a (`static`/non-`static`) member function based on input.

Comment: Do you mean that all your Monster's at once will became 'hard' as static intend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a normal function (not a non-static member function) which asks for input from the user and returns a bool value:

```
bool AskUser()
{
    ....
}
```

Then simply use the return value of that function to initialize your static member.

```
const bool Monster::hard = AskUser();
```

Just to clear things up, here is a complete, compileable example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool AskUser();

class Monster
{
public:
    static bool IsHard() { return hard; }
private:
    static const bool hard;
};

int main()
{
    if (Monster::IsHard())
        std::cout << "it is hard\n";
    else
        std::cout << "it is not hard\n";
}

bool AskUser()
{
    std::cout << "hard? ";
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    return input.size() && input[0] == 'y';            
}

const bool Monster::hard = AskUser();
```

If you want more control over when this initialization happens, you will have to drop your requirement for `const`.  It shouldn't really be a problem though, as long as the member is private, you can still have complete control over whether it is changed. e.g.

```
class Monster
{
public:
    static void SetHard()
    {
        static bool hard_is_set = false;
        if (hard_is_set)
            return;
        hard_is_set = true;
        hard = AskUser();
    }
private:
    static bool hard;
};

bool Monster::hard;
```

One possible problem here is that it is possible to call the `SetHard` function outside of `main` (e.g. in the initialization of another static object), if that happens, it may access the static member before it is actually created, resulting in undefined behavior. (`static` objects are tricky things and should be treated with care). So don't do that.

Comment: one question will this line of code will be executed? It's not code in main() this is just random code in a class

Comment: @LittleJacod: It is executed before main. The line should be somewhere in the global scope (not inside a function) in a piece of code that is only compiled once (i.e. not in a header file).

Comment: Really then the first thing that the program will do before main starts will be asking a user.

Comment: @AlexeyVoytenko: Not necessarily the first thing, but yes, it has to happen before `main`.  For a `static const` member, there is no other possibility.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I know but for me it would be some strange program :)
isHard could be non const at all and really non static (mutable then).

Comment: With this solution you cannot control the order of initialization of static objects. If you do this for two objects then neither can safely use the other because it might not be initialized yet. Other static may or may not have had their constructors run yet. The user interface might not be initialized yet (if you ever expand this program). In short, it's a can of worms.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Yep. I'm currently in the process of editing with a solution for that problem.

Comment: Wow guys I really thank you for your answers, they helped me to clear the scene a bit, I decided to do so because i thought i would be easier than creating a new Spawner class but it turned out the opposite! Thanks again i really appreciaty your help